# Знает ли github-репозиторий о heroku-репозитории

Tags: git, github, heroku

Есть проект: develop ветка которого торчит на github, а master ветка с разными конфигурационными файлами заливается на heroku.
Вопрос: если кто-то выкачает репозиторий с github, он сможет узнать об удаленном репозитории heroku?

Comment: Если у вас всё хранится в ветке `master`, то безусловно. Репозиторий это (практически) неделимая сущность, если я могу прочитать ветку `develop`, то и `master` могу.

Comment: Просто не храните никакие секретные файлы в репозитории.